# Fiddler soap action in proxy client

Tags: soap

This is what fiddler has to say for a request I am trying to make to an external webservice

```
Request:  
POST https://service100.emedny.org:9047/MHService HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Host: service100.emedny.org:9047
Content-Length: 7933
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive


Response: HTTP 500 Internal server error. 
Miscellaneous: X-backside-transport: FAIL FAIL
TextView: Faultcode-Rejected by policy from client
```

Could  soap Action =”” be the probable cause of this Faultcode? I am sure a client handshake was established

Now this is the trace viewer svclog
[image]

THank you